# Telerik Radgrid required field issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, telerik, radgrid

I have a radgrid displayed on a page and am wanting to make a particular field required when in insert and edit mode but don't necessarily know how to go about this.

Comment: Can you post the code for your grid? Depending on whether you are using templates, forms etc the answer will vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular validators

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
        runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Like this:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
  <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ContactName" UniqueName="TemplateColumn">
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContactName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContactName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
      <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
      </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-validation.html

Comment: The link was able to show me the missing properties for I was missing in my gridboundcolumn - thanks!

Comment: @Dalorzo, I got this working for requiredvalidator scenario however there is one scenario where I need to not display this column which I managed through 
"RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn("TemplateColumn").Display=false;" it hides the column but reqvalidator is still enabled. any idea how can I make that validator disable from the code behind during inserts-updates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For common validation like required field, I found RadGrid has it built-in support
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/validation

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ShipName" HeaderText="ShipName" UniqueName="ShipName">
<ColumnValidationSettings EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true" EnableModelErrorMessageValidation="true">
    <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="This field is required"></RequiredFieldValidator>
    <ModelErrorMessage BackColor="Red" />
</ColumnValidationSettings>
```

> where **ModelErrorMessage** control validation is available only in .NET 4.5 when *ModelBinding* is used.